# Can I call a function in R if it's argument is not defined?

Tags: r, function

Out of pure curiosity, I want to make a function in R that creates a new variable. I don't want the function to ask the user for input while it is running. Suppose x is not currently a variable. Below is an example of what I want the code to do:

```
def=function(x){
x=NULL
}

def(x)
x
NULL.
```

Comment: Curiosity is fine, but don't do this in your actual code. Side effects are bad and lead to errors that can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

substitute allows you to delay evaluation of the variable, `as.character` turns it into the typed name, if we then assign it in the parent.frame() to the value, we get what you're after.

```
def <- function(x) {
    y <- substitute(x)
    assign(as.character(y),NULL,envir = parent.frame())
}

> def(test)
> test
NULL
```

Comment: I was going to add an answer but it ended up pretty similar to this. I'd add a test for `x` in the `parent.frame()` before assigning, to make sure you're not overwriting anything: `if (!exists(as.character(y), where = parent.frame())) assign()`.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure that wasn't desired behavior, but yes that's almost certainly a safer way to go. If that's what the poster is after, I'll add it.